# GitLab CI maven Project deploy to Artifactory Exception Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, artifactory, gitlab-ci

Good day collegues. I am trying to implement gitlab-ci in my project. I have created all stage and they work except deploying.
As a teaching material and example, I used the following article: https://jfrog.com/blog/gitlab-and-artifactory-on-your-mark-get-set-build/

I have a stage in gitlab-ci file:

```
deploy-artifactory-snapshot:
  image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
  stage: deploy-artifactory
  tags:
  - release
  before_script:
  # Install JFrog CLI
  -  curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
  # Configure Artifactory instance with JFrog CLI
  - ./jfrog rt config --url=${ARTIFACTORY_URL} --user=${ARTIFACTORY_USER} --password=${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}
  - ./jfrog rt c show
  # Set the M2_HOME environment variable
  - export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
  # Replace the repository name in the configuration.yml to the correct one.
  - sed -i 's,MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_DEPLOYER,'"$MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_DEPLOYER"',g' configuration.yml
  - sed -i 's,MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_DEPLOYER,'"$MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_DEPLOYER"',g' configuration.yml
  - sed -i 's,MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_RESOLVER,'"$MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_RESOLVER"',g' configuration.yml
  - sed -i 's,MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_RESOLVER,'"$MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_RESOLVER"',g' configuration.yml
  script:
  # Run the MVN command
  - ./jfrog rt mvn "clean install" configuration.yml --build-name=scdfrestrunner --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
  # Collect the environment variables
  - ./jfrog rt bce gitlabci-maven-artifactory $CI_JOB_ID
  # Pass the build information to Artifactory
  - ./jfrog rt bp gitlabci-maven-artifactory $CI_JOB_ID

  only:
  - develop
```

This is my configuration.yml property file for Jfrog app:

```
version: 1
type: maven
resolver:
  snapshotRepo: MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_RESOLVER
  releaseRepo: MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_RESOLVER
  serverID: Default-Server
deployer:
  snapshotRepo: MAVEN_REPO_SNAPSHOT_DEPLOYER
  releaseRepo: MAVEN_REPO_RELEASES_DEPLOYER
  serverID: Default-Server
```

Every time i trying to deploy my artifact via gitlab-ci i get next exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing
>   artifact to Artifactory:
>   /builds/Aleksandr.Shapovalov/scdfrestrunner/target/scdf-rest-runner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
>   Skipping deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info.
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:316)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:173)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException:
>   Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)  at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2369)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2348)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2325)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2273)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1041)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1066)     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:234)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:225)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:687)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:374)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:362)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:347)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:314)
>     ... 19 more

Could someone describe me where i am wrong.
Artifactory version is 6.0.1
GitLab Community Edition 11.1.4

**UPDATE:**

It looks like there are no any connectivity problems, i see my build agent is downloading from our artifactory. For example one of many lines:

> Downloaded:
>   https://artifactory.mycompany.net:443/artifactory/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom
>   (12 kB at 17 kB/s) Downloading:
>   https://artifactory.mycompany.net:443/artifactory/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom

My stage falls right after this line:

> [main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder -
>   Deploying artifact:
>   https://artifactory.mycompany.net:443/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/net/mycompany/scdf-rest-runner/1.0-SNAPSHOT/scdf-rest-runner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: It looks like a connectivity problem:

Comment: It looks like a connectivity problem: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body I suggest checking if you can access your Artifactory instance from the build agent.

Comment: There are shoudn't any connectivity problem. I see it downloads  something from our artifactory:
Downloaded: https://artifactory.mycompany.net:443/artifactory/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom (12 kB at 17 kB/s)
Downloading: https://artifactory.mycompany.net:443/artifactory/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom

Comment: If your artifactory is behind some reverse proxy / load balancer, you should check the logs there (access and error).
Also check artifactory logs, system and request. It  might be a limitation on body size at the reverse proxy / load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if the artifact you are trying to push already exists in the registry (artifactory)

I was able to reproduce the issue when I do so.

```
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:784)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:751)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:266)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:225)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1680)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1659)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1636)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1611)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:668)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:225)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:216)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:680)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:355)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:340)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.deployArtifacts(DeployTask.java:262)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.prepareAndDeploy(DeployTask.java:113)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.collectProjectBuildInfo(DeployTask.java:50)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.taskAction(DeployTask.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
```